# how can I get File Icon?

Tags: c#

how can I get File Icon ?

Also how can I get file small thumbnail ?

Answer (score 21):

For the associated icon, you can use:

```
string filename = "path-to-file";
Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename);
```